# Font size appears bold when made bigger

Tags: html, css

CSS problem with fonts, it appears simple but could not figure out....

p - normal paragraph fonts in range 100% - 109% - looks normal, thin fonts;

when I put font-size: 110% (or 120%) - fonts turn Bold (strong) - it is nowhere in code they should be bold; but they look like bold;

I was trying to put some extra for font-weight: 400 or 500 - no success....

I sometimes need Bigger but THIN fonts of 120%; but I can have only up to 109%

p.s. Nothing special about code there

```
font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,"DejaVu Sans",sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; font-size: 100%; //works font-size:110%; // appears bold...
```

Comment: Please post a code example in your question.

Comment: it depends on the font. it might have a thinner variant you need to use instead

Comment: Adding to what chiliNUT says, you may want to look into embedding the fonts with the faces you need. (typekit, etc).